# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix Admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I got a problem in my layout where Im trying to add the Admob.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/lined2"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id ="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fillparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="My ID"
    ad:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testdevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

So the Error is in this line :

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
```

It says :

```
Error parsing XML:unbound prefix
```

I really searched many Posts but no one helped me...
I allready add the line with add xmlns:ads .... but It doesnt help :/
Did I forgot sth. ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You haven't closed the `RelativeLayout` tag

Comment: `ads:adUnitId="My ID"
 ad **s** :adSize="BANNER"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `s` in the namespace for `adSize`.

Change

```
ad:adSize="BANNER"
```

to

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id ="@+id/adview"
android:layout_width="fillparent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="My ID"
**ads:adSize="BANNER"**
ads:testdevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

correction.